# chrome extension to get URL not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I tried making a chrome extension that could give URL string of current tab of current window.
I had seen similar questions but, don't know why mine is not working.
I had taken care of deprecated calls as well.
[Here it is](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1i4hx35ztrp5de7/chrome_geturl.zip?dl=0)

I have even properly set the permissions in manifest.json file.
But it's not working.
Here are main js file code

//background.js

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
      // Send a message to the active tab
      chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
        var activeTab = tabs[0];
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(activeTab.id, {"message": "clicked_browser_action"});
      });
    });
```

//content.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if( request.message === "clicked_browser_action" ) {
      var firstHref = $("a[href^='http']").eq(0).attr("href");

      //console.log(firstHref);
      alert(firstHref);
    }
  }
);
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Working code may help you https://github.com/MrPardeep/Angular2_typescript_ChromeExtension/blob/master/scripts/AppComponent.component.ts , you can try by running this extension too

Comment: That's okay, But could you point as to why my code is not working

Comment: amm okay wait for a moment let me check once your code

Comment: sure, I am waiting for my code as well to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you havn't add your HTML file in your manifest file thts why your project is not working,
make some changes in your manifest.json like this :-

```
.......
"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }, 
 ....some code here//
```

Alternatively you can see here too for working extension of chrome

> - https://github.com/MrPardeep/Angular2_typescript_ChromeExtension

## Edit2

Change your background.js with this code :-

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  var link = document.getElementById('btn');
  // onClick's logic below:
  link.addEventListener('click', function () {
    AddUrl();
  });


  function AddUrl() {
    chrome.tabs.query({ currentWindow: true, active: true }, function (tabs) {
      alert(tabs[0].url)
      // document.getElementById('Current_url').value = tabs[0].url;
      console.log(tabs[0].url, tabs[0].title, tabs[0].incognito, tabs, this.bookmark_title);
    });
  }
});
```

and popup.html with this code :-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<script src="background.js"></script>

<body>
    <h1>This is a Heading</h1>
    <button id="btn"> Click Me </button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: but it is popping up only html text, not URL

Comment: that's okay, but can you tell how could i let it popup URL?

Comment: sorry but click event does nothing....meanwhile I am as well looking the code for correction

Comment: @Guru check console, i have tested this code before update answer

Comment: i have added alert in my answer, check now